# R Markdown how to make parameter optional

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is there a way to make a parameter optional in R Markdown when using knitr? Below is a stand-alone example, my simple attempt to omit a parameter, and the error.

**Example RMD file:**

````
---
title: "`r params$name`"
date: \`r format(Sys.Date(), "%B %d, %Y")`\
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
params:
    name: NA
    A: NA
    B: NA
    C: NA
--- 
# Header-1

`r params$A` 
`r params$B`
```{r, echo=FALSE, out.width="50%"}
knitr::include_graphics(params$C)
```
````

**Example run script:**

```
render(input = "mytemplate.Rmd", 
       output_file = "fileout.html", 
       params = list(
         name = 'Bob', 
         A = 'turkey', 
         B = 'otter'
         )
       )
```

**Resulting error when omitting "C":**

```
Error in knitr::include_graphics(params$C) : 
  Cannot find the file(s): NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not passing `C` value in `params` works fine for me. It prints the default value (`NA`) in the HTML output. I get an error because `name` is not declared. Using the below works -

```
---
title: "`r params$name`"
date: \`r format(Sys.Date(), "%B %d, %Y")`\
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
params:
    A: NA
    B: NA
    C: NA
    name: NA
--- 
# Header-1

`r params$A` 
`r params$B`
`r params$C`
```

and calling it with

```
rmarkdown::render(input = "mytemplate.Rmd", 
       output_file = "fileout.html", 
       params = list(
         name = 'Bob', 
         A = 'turkey', 
         B = 'otter'
       )
)
```

---

For the updated question you can add an `if` condition :

````
`r params$A` 
`r params$B`
```{r, echo=FALSE, out.width="50%"}
if(params$C != 'NA') knitr::include_graphics(params$C)
````

Comment: I'm sorry, I copy/paste the wrong RMD; you are right, it works mostly fine. The issue I am having is that the parameter points to a JPG (OP updated).

Comment: You can add an `if` condition, see updated answer.